# What kind of member is btnode *rt()?

Tags: c++

This is part of my code, it's not the full thing:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int c,f;

struct btnode
{
  btnode *left;
  int data;
  btnode *right;
};

class bt
{
  private:
  btnode *root;

public:
bt()
{
  root=NULL;
}
btnode * rt()
{
  return root;
}
```

Can someone tell me what `btnode *rt()` is called? Is it a constructor or a method?

Comment: `rt()` returns a pointer to your root node.

Comment: constructor is also a method, albeit a special one. constructor in this case is `bt()`. `btnode * rt()` means this method is returning something of the type `btnode`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a class for binary tree.

btnode *rt() is the method that returns the root of the binary tree (by a pointer of type btnode).

bt() is your constructor that initializes root to null first.

Answer (score 1):

`bt()`is a constructor, recognized by having the class name and no return type. That is a special type of member function.

`btnode* rt()` is an ordinary member function, sometimes also called a method as that is common in some other languages. Here it could also be called an accessor function, as its purpose is to give you access to a (private) class member.